# Build a app to remind 6 times a day in different time a whole year?

Tags: ios, time, reminders

I am a beginner and would like to make an app for iOS. I do not know where to start but I am not sure whether you can make an app that remembers you every day for a year at different times (I have time to write them in) .. ? Can you make something which can run in the background as the program 'Reminder'?

I will also have it's different in another selected city ..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use local notification for that.

See [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=nsnotification%20tutorial&aq=1&oq=nsnotification%20&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3j62l2.6813j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=nsnotification%20tutorial%20%2b%20ios%20sdk&oq=nsnotification%20tutorial%20%2b%20ios%20sdk&gs_l=serp.3..33i29i30.17555.20020.0.20251.10.9.0.0.0.0.437.1505.0j1j0j3j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.TFYQZsf7My0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45580626,d.bmk&fp=e43e71261d25a34d&biw=1020&bih=582).

You can set time difference as per your requirement.

And even if your app is not running, or is not in background. It will work.

Like this,

```
local.fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

See this [link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/97768-ios-fire-local-notification-every-day-on-specific-time.html) or [this](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/112104-update-alert-body-every-day-on-local-notification.html) , you will get the hint.

Comment: But where to write the time & date in the program ?

Comment: Thanx, I will try and turn back . I am new so it takes time :b

Answer (score -1):

you cant run a program in the background all the time in IOS,
you can do 2 things:

1. you can add reminders to the calendar, so your app wont need to run all the time, only once      to add it.
2. you can use push notifications and just send push to the users every time you want it, so all calculations will be on some php or java or any other server you want.

Comment: yes I want it the send a push notifications in the times I wrote down in the program ? Can I ?

Comment: in that case as i said, you need a backend server with cronjob to send the notifications to the users